# Image Processing: how to find factor x and y of resizing image knowing that the object has an angle up to 90°

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computational-geometry

I built such classification model that takes as input an image of such rectangular object that has fixed dimensions (w0 x h0). the output of the model is the class of this object.., where w0 = 742 pixels and h0 = 572 pixels

now I have the same problem but with bigger rectangular object that has new fixed dimensions (w x h), where w = 1077 pixels and h = 681 pixels.

I would like to resize the new image so that the object will have exactly the same size of the old object to fit the current model I already built. How can I find the x and y factors of the image resizing knowing that the object is not straight and can has an angle alpha from 0° to 90°? alpha is known for me.

currently I have a bad solution:

1. rotate the image -alpha
2. resize the image using factor x = x0/x and y = y0/y
3. rotate the image back (+alpha)

Is it possible to calculate the resizing factors with respect of the angle alpha so I only resize the image without rotating the image back and forth? or maybe you know such function in opencv that does this calcuation?

Comment: You surely have images you could share to clarify your goal? And corresponding alpha value? Is the rectangular object's face always perpendicular to the optical axis of the lens?

Comment: Your transformation is affine, and its matrix can be obtained as the product of the matrices of the transformations 3, 2, 1. Compute the matrix and apply warpAffine.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: yes, the object is perpendicular to the optical axis of the objective. sorry but I don't have enough privileges to share the images. I already asked my client to allow me to share few.